# How to configure a beforeEach function before a test in Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I use `beforeEach` like this in my tests for React components.

```
let component;
let configProp;

beforeEach(() => {
  component = shallow(<MyComponent config={configProp} />);
});
```

Now, I want to change `configProp` variable in tests. Something like this:

```
let component;
let configProp;

beforeEach(() => {
  component = shallow(<MyComponent config={configProp} />);
});

// runs before beforeEach for the next test
beforeNext(() => {
    const config_1 = {...};
    configProp = config_1;
});

test('config_1', () => {
  // component now has config=config_1
  expect(component.find({config: config_1}).exists());
});
```

Is something like this possible? Or, do we have to `shallow(<MyComponent />)` in every test individually?

Right now, I'm using an `it` block to make the configuration changes for the next function. Is this legit? Something like this:

```
it('changes configProp', () => {
    const config_1 = {...};
    configProp = config_1;
});

test('config_1', () => {
  expect(component.find({config: config_1}).exists());
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set new prop on component inside test:

```
test('config_1', () => {
  component.setProps({ config: configProp });
  ...
})
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help you ;)